# Gradle bundle import to module

Tags: gradle

I am trying to import `base` to a project, but I get an error.

settings.gradle

```
enableFeaturePreview('VERSION_CATALOGS')
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core
            version('spring', '5.3.14')
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter
            version('spring-boot', '2.6.2')

            alias('spring-core').to('org.springframework', 'spring-core').versionRef('spring')
            alias('spring-context').to('org.springframework', 'spring-context').versionRef('spring')


            alias('spring-boot').to('org.springframework.boot', 'spring-boot-starter').versionRef('spring-boot')

            bundle('base', ['spring-core', 'spring-context'])
        }
    }
}
```

module's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.base)

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}
```

refreshing gradle will produce the following error

> Could not get unknown property 'base' for extension 'libs' of type org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.

How to import `libs.base` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of referencing a bundle from a version catalog is

```
libs.bundles.base
```

Similarly for plugins use:

```
libs.plugins.yourplugin
```

It is also possible to reference versions, but this works slightly different. For example:

```
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web-services", version: libs.versions.spring.boot.get()
```

This assumes a version definition in your catalog which looks like:

```
version('spring-boot', '2.6.7')
```

Note that bundles, versions and plugins are all spelled as plural.

Also note that as of Gradle 7 version catalogs are no longer a feature preview. They are available by default. Also, the notation for libraries has changed slightly. You have to use `library` instead of `alias`.

See [Gradle's support site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) for more information.